# Scala: rdd countApprox usage

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to try using countApprox to estimate a repartition of an oversized rdd (currently getting heartbeat Exception)

I understand the call is as follows

```
val countApprox:PartialResult[BoundedDouble]=rddlp.countApprox(3000,0.95)
```

However, I am not quite sure how to process the return variable

As I understand...

1. I wait for the calculation to complete by calling `getFinalValue`:

   `val countApprox:BoundedDouble=rddlp.countApprox(30000,0.95).getFinalValue()`
2. The bounded double gives me a confidence for its calculation. If I am happy with the confidence level, I do something. If not, I probably bow out.

   ```
     countApprox.confidence match
     {  
        case x if(x>0.9) =>
              val usefulValue=countApprox.mean
        case _ => ....walk away
     }
   ```
3. I have a choice of `high`, `low` and `mean` estimate to use as my `usefulValue`

**QUESTIONS.**
Is this correct and is this standard usage? Also, (I know this is more an art than a science), but what are the criteria for determining a useful confidence level?